# Delete Duplicates based on multiple columns but select the "most" complete version of the duplicates by least NA's

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have a code that looks like this

```
  Month|  Day|   Year| Color|   Weather|Location|Transporation|ID
  Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    Warm    Hospital    NA         1
  Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    Warm     NA         NA         1
  Jan     Tue    2020   Blue    NA       NA         NA         1
  Feb     Thu    2020   Red     NA       NA         NA         2
  Feb     Thu    2020   Red     Warm     NA         NA         2
  Feb     Thu    2020   Red     Warm    Garden      Run        2
  Mar     Thu    2020   Red     Cold    Desk        Bus        3
```

I would like it to look like this

```
Month|   Day|  Year|   Color|  Weather|Location|  Transporation|ID
Jan      Tue   2020    Blue    Warm    Hospital   NA            1
Feb      Thu   2020     Red    Warm    Garden     Run           2
Mar      Thu   2020     Red    Cold    Desk       Bus           3
```

Basically I want to decide if a column is a duplicate by selecting three `c(ID,Month,Color)`. Once a duplicate is determined I want it to remove the one with most NA's or "least completed" as in the less columns filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this would work, I did rowSums(is.na()) to list how many missing items by row, then grouped by ID, Month, Color, and filtered to the row with the least amount of missing:

```
library(dplyr)
dat<-data.frame("Month" = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar"),
                "Day" = c("Tue", "Tue", "Tue", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu"),
                "Year" = rep(2020,7),
                "Color" = c(rep("Blue", 3), rep("Red", 4)),
                "Weather" = c("Warm", "Warm", NA, NA, "Warm", "Warm", "Cold"),
                "Location" = c("Hospital", rep(NA, 4), "Garden", "Desk"),
                "Transporation" = c(rep(NA, 5), "Run", "Bus"),
                "ID" = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3)
)%>%
  mutate(Missing = rowSums(is.na(.)))%>% #Making a sum of how many missing items per row
  group_by(ID, Month, Color)%>%
  filter(Missing == min(Missing))%>% #Filtering to the least amount of missing
  ungroup()%>%
  select(-Missing) #Removing the missing column as it was only used to filter
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use an `order` to select the first non-NA element after grouping by the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(Month, Day, Year) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ first(.[order(is.na(.))])), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  Month Day    Year Color Weather Location Transporation    ID
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
1 Feb   Thu    2020 Red   Warm    Garden   Run               2
2 Jan   Tue    2020 Blue  Warm    Hospital <NA>              1
3 Mar   Thu    2020 Red   Cold    Desk     Bus               3
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Month = c("Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", 
"Mar"), Day = c("Tue", "Tue", "Tue", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu"
), Year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), Color = c("Blue", 
"Blue", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red"), Weather = c("Warm", 
"Warm", NA, NA, "Warm", "Warm", "Cold"), Location = c("Hospital", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Garden", "Desk"), Transporation = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Run", "Bus"), ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table library, if your data is already in j:

```
j <- as.data.table(your_data)
j

    Month    Day  Year  Color Weather Location Transporation    ID
   <char> <char> <int> <char>  <char>   <char>        <char> <int>
1:    Jan    Tue  2020   Blue    Warm Hospital          <NA>     1
2:    Jan    Tue  2020   Blue    Warm     <NA>          <NA>     1
3:    Jan    Tue  2020   Blue    <NA>     <NA>          <NA>     1
4:    Feb    Thu  2020    Red    <NA>     <NA>          <NA>     2
5:    Feb    Thu  2020    Red    Warm     <NA>          <NA>     2
6:    Feb    Thu  2020    Red    Warm   Garden           Run     2
7:    Mar    Thu  2020    Red    Cold     Desk           Bus     3

j$n_na  <- apply(j, MARGIN = 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
setorder(j,n_na)
k <- unique(j,by=c("ID","Month","Color"))
setorder(k,ID)
k

    Month    Day  Year  Color Weather Location Transporation    ID  n_na
   <char> <char> <int> <char>  <char>   <char>        <char> <int> <int>
1:    Jan    Tue  2020   Blue    Warm Hospital          <NA>     1     1
2:    Feb    Thu  2020    Red    Warm   Garden           Run     2     0
3:    Mar    Thu  2020    Red    Cold     Desk           Bus     3     0
```

After all k will hold the data as your require.
Regards, Miguel